# Instances are shaking when using geometry proximity node

Tags: geometry-nodes, geometry, instances

I am making a simple animation using the amazing *Geometry Proximity*, and I have a little problem: the instances shake weirdly when the proximity target object moves ahead.

Here is the node tree:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you please share your blend file via https://blend-exchange.com/? The way the question is currently worded, it is not clear what is actually the goal, and also the node tree cannot be reconstructed due to a too low resolution of your screenshot (Please always use Blender's built-in function for screenshots). Please be so kind and complete your question with the necessary information. Thank you!

Comment: I added my blend file, and I cannot really explain the error, the crystals are just shaking weirdly instead of just growing and shrinking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can solve this task completely with *Geometry Nodes*, but you would have to build the spiral, which you use for distance measurement, differently.

[image]

In your case, you move and rotate an existing spiral from the bottom to the top, which does not allow you to determine a constant distance. Therefore, your instances "wobble".

Instead of creating a spiral as a mesh beforehand and animating it with keyframes along the Z-axis, you would simply have to create a spiral with *Geometry Nodes*.

You then influence the length of the spiral with the node `Trim Curve`, whereby the topology remains constant and the growing crystals also have a constant size.

[image]

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.4+)*</sub>

Comment: Thank you so much for such a detailed explanation. You are awesome!